# How to loop scrape data inside span (arrows) and loop it all in consecutive pages?

Tags: python, loops, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first time trying to use python with selenium and bs4.
I'm trying to scrape data from this [website](http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it)

To begin I select GE from cantone dropdown menu, click the checkbox "Conffermo" and the button "Ricerca". Then I can see the data. I have to click each arrow to expand the data and scrape it from every person (this is a loop, isn't it). And then do the same on the next page (by clicking on "Affiggere le seguenti entrate" at the bottom of the page)

I'd like to use relative xpath for the data since not all persons have all the data (I'd like to put an empty cell in excel when data is missing)

This is my code so far:

```
  import urllib2
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  URL = 'http://www.asca.ch/Partners.aspx?lang=it'
  time.sleep(10)
  page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page) # query the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, ‘html.parser’) 
  inputElementCantone = driver.find_element_by_xpath(//*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ddl_cantons_Input"]).click()
  browser.find_element_by_xpath(/html/body/form/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[9]).click()
  browser.find_element_by_xpath(//INPUT[@id='MainContent__chkDisclaimer']).click()
  driver.find_element_by_xpath(//INPUT[@id='MainContent_btn_submit']).click() 
  arrow = browser.find_element_by_class_name("footable-toggle")
```

I'm stuck after this. The data I'd like to scrape (in excel columns) are: Discipline(s) thérapeutique(s), Cognome, Cellulare and email.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
# To find all the table 
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'footable'})

# To get all rows in that table
rows = table.find_all('tr')

# A function to process each row
def processRow(row):
    #All rows with hidden data
    dataFields = row.find_all('td', {'style': True}
    output = {}
    #Fixed index numbers are not ideal but in this case will work
    output['Discipline'] = dataFields[0].text
    output['Cogome'] = dataFields[2].text
    output['Cellulare'] = dataFields[8].text
    output['email'] = dataFields[10].text
    return output


#Declaring a list to store all results
results = []

#Iterating over all the rows and storing the processed result in a list
for row in rows:
    results.append(processRow(row))

print(results)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply and thank you for your help. I tried it, but I think I'm getting the wrong data. There is a double data in the first 2 columns with NPA numbers instead of Cellulare and Cognome. Nothing at Discipline column and phone numbers at the email column. I was thinking to find a way of addressing the data by their sibling using XPath. Let's say the sibling for "Cellulare" would be "022 328 23 44" I have the relative XPath but don't know how to use it.